# Upload image to imgur api keeps responding error":"Authentication required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, imgur

I have been trying to upload an image with imgur api and react, but I keep getting the same error even though I am including my Client ID.

imgur docs: https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139

the response from the server:

```
{"data":{"error":"Authentication required","request":"\/3\/image","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":401}
```

This is how I get the image:

```
 <input
            type="file"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            ref={(fileInput) => (this.fileInput = fileInput)}
            onChange={this.uploadImg}
          />
```

Here is the onChange function:

```
uploadImg(e) {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", e.target.files[0]);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization: "Client-ID xxx",
      },
    };
    axios.post("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", config, data);
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I have been trying to do it for the past couple of hours and couldn't find anything to help me solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve this issue.
The problem was with my post request, apparently it takes data as the first argument and options as the second.

Changing this line:

```
axios.post("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", config, data);
```

With this line:

```
axios.post("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", data, config);
```

Seems to have solved the issue